# How to sanitize this particular mysql query?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

i got this SQL query where post_title taken from $_GET

> $sql = "SELECT ID FROM posts WHERE posts.post_title = '5-design-web-colourful'";

What is the best way to sanitize this and make it more safe ?

EDIT : (as requested)  I'm trying to create a plugin that work to hide a particular category (named private) and all of its post for every non-logged guest. i have hook into 'pre_get_posts' and 'posts_selection' able to control how to show particular posts and category for admin, the member who wrote them, other member, and guest.

The category must be non exist. so it can not be shown on cat archive page in front end.

I know it's not relatedto the question cause what iask just how to sanitize name / title of a post. nothing more.

Comment: So you want to make sure that an _identifier_ isn't tampered with. Is the column name `$wpdb->posts.post_title` the only "issue" or can `$wpdb->posts` be a problem, too?

Comment: VolkerK: I read the question to mean that '5-desain-web-colourful' (i.e. value of post_title field) was taken from $_GET.  Can you please clarify, justjoe?

Comment: @all : sorry, this is wordpress query. i will edit those sql first

Comment: Now, in _this_ version of the query, you don't have to sanitize _anything_. It's a static query with no variable parts. You might want to _explain_ what you're trying to achieve. And now it becomes more and more likely the question is a duplicate.

Comment: "sorry, this is wordpress query" - so you are "within" wordpress, i.e. you don't use mysql\_query() but the $wpdb object to access the database?

Comment: @volkerk : yes, that's i try to do. btw, maybe you have heard WP_QUERY, a query class of wordpress. i'm try to sanitize its request and took id of particular post title. hopefully, the sanitize version will be safer

Comment: Please(!) edit your question again and explain in a lot(!) more detail what you're trying to achieve. E.g. are you using WP\_QUERY "on your own" or do you think there is a bug in wordpress that causes $wp\_query to perform an insecure query?

Comment: ...and can you tell us a bit more about how you end up with `$sql ='....';` and how it's supposed to interact with WP\_QUERY and what you're going to do with it? Sorry for nagging, but I still think this doesn't cover it (yet). Because how to sanitize depends on what wordpress objects/function you use, where this query really originates from and so on. Or do you by-pass wordpress at this point and connect to the database directly?

Comment: @volkerk : firstly, i sorry if i make you assume that there's something wrong with $wpdb. my code took $wp_query->request and sanitize it. then took the requested url (it assume as a post title) then i have to check whether this belong to category or not. Nah, this why i need wpdb...when we're attaching our function in a hook, especially if the hook initiative earlier then other wordpress hook, our option of build-in function become limited. i clone $wpdb and use it to check whther the request belong to what category...that's all...hoefully i don't bored you ;D

Comment: I'm not bored but (no offence) maybe a bit annoyed... because there is something to the question. It could be a good question but right now imho it's a mess. It started as a mysql question (having only identifiers as variables), you got the generic mysql\_escape\_lalala  answers (potentially wrong at this point), turns out you really want variable sql parameters, ok real\_escape\_string might be it. Suddenly it becomes a wordpress question (-> real\_escape\_string not good), WP\_QUERY gets involved. Now it's wpdb (probably both, WP\_QUERY and wpdb) ....c'mon, it's a bit all over the place.

Comment: @Volkerk hahaha your're right. i'm asking the question when i'm in the middle of coding it. i have too little experience with security. That's why i ask this simple question, before you asked me to explain it,  the original question is about how to sanitize $sql  query. that's all. Right now i had finish the plugin. Thanks's to Franz's answer, i'm little bit sure about the sql part ;D ... i code it with a friend..here the working example... work.bakawan.com

Comment: Ok, but please keep in mind that when you're using wpdb/WP\_QUERY you're not supposed to use mysql\_real\_escape\_string() directly. Use the methods exposed by those two classes, e.g. $wpdb->escape() or $wpdbb->prepare(). That's why context matters.

Comment: @Volkerk : hmm, i see. i will keep it in mind. in the end, i use $wpdb->prepare(). this is the only method i aware of. i have not use $wpdb->escape before. so i hesitate. But i promise i will read more before use it. btw, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, assuming you use MySQL.

Comment: For the string you insert only, I may add:
`... $wpdb->posts.post_title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($str)."'";`

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, the better approach is to use bind parameters.  This protects you from all attack vectors of this category.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

For your example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select id from $wpdb->posts where $wpdb->posts.post_title = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $str);
$sth->execute();
```

**CAUTION:** This assumes that $wpdb is safe!

Comment: seems to me that the OP meant this, though.